# how to make simple marker biostall CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

my controller file:

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');

$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1419';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

my view file:

```
<html>
<head><?php echo $map['js']; ?></head>
<body><?php echo $map['html']; ?></body>
</html>
```

and i have CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library in my folder libraries project.

my source file : https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library

and this the result :
[image]

i ask to google but, she suggest me to make API_KEY in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

now, i have api key, but how to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your googlemaps.php on your library,

find this variable

```
var $apiKey='';
```

and fill it with your API key,like

```
var $apiKey='your API key';
```